# Using static Datasets inside ForeachRDD in Java Spark Streaming for DStreams RDD parallel processing

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have DStreams which is consuming JSON messages using custom receiver. This JSON messages is nothing but a user request in the form of some input parameteres.

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> msgDStream = ssc.receiverStream(receiver);
```

Another thing is i have static Dataset(preloaded) for e.g.

```
Dataset<Row> loanDS = spark.read().parquet("/path")
```

Now in my use case, i want to process DStream RDDs data(JSON messages) parallely

```
msgDStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
@Override
public void call(JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD) throws Exception {
if(!stringJavaRDD.isEmpty()) {

System.out.println("Json string: " + requestJSON);
stringJavaRDD.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>(){
public void call(String s) throws Exception{
parseJSON(s); // externam utility to parse the JSON messages
{here i want to build aggregate clause, select clause based on the static dataset loanDS with the JSON messages}
}
});
}}});
```

When i use loandDS inside stringJavaRDD.foreach, it does not have anything because foreach executes on the worker nodes and loanDS is present on Driver.

How to achieve this inside foreach because i want to process JSON messages inside DStream RDD's parallely.

Comment: First of all - loanDS is not on the Driver. Same as RDD, Dataset is distributed collection. 
Second - you can't use operations on RDDs/Datasets inside of `foreach()` action.
Third - you need to do whatever you want in `foreachRDD` function. I did not quite understand what you're trying to achieve, but i suspect that you need to join RDD with Dataset in `foreachRDD` somehow.

Comment: Say for eg. in stringJavaRDD i have 2 JSON messages as a String coming from receiver, now i want to join these 2 JSON messages inside stringJavaRDD parallely with loanDS Datasets. How to achieve parallelism of each JSON messages inside the DStrea RDDs. I know DStream RDDs are processed sequentially but my concern is to process the content of DStream RDDs parallely.

Comment: Ah. I see. Indeed `foreachRDD` is executed sequentially. But RDD and Dataset processing will happen in parallel. It does not differ in any way from batch processing in Spark. So that means whatever processing you will do inside `foreachRDD` for your RDDs and Datasets - it will work in parallel.

Comment: yes right .. Our use case for the parallel implementation of RDD of DStreams